# Spring JPA @Transactional data accessing

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

im having trouble resolving or handling data between my `@Transational` methods. Or i may have a wrong understanding of `@Transactionl`.

This is my scenario

`Method A`

```
@Transactional
public void methodA {
   MyEntity e = myRepo.findByid(1).orElseThrow();

   e.setMyFlag(1123);

   methodB();

   myRepo.save(e);
}


@Transactional 
public void methodB {
    MyEntity e = myRepo.findByMyFlag(1123).orElseThrow(); <--- This throws Not Found Exception
    // do something 'e' entity that is having a myFlag = 1123
    // i am not modifying the entity just doing something externally 
    // using myFlag value 1123
}
```

My understanding is that, `methodB` is using the session in `methodA`. Now, given that it is using the same session, i can get the data set in `methodA` that was not yet commited or `save()` is not yet called. Please do correct me if i am wrong and point me to the correct one. Also, the above scenario is what i wanted to achieve.

FYI i also tried moving `methodB` call after `save()` call. Still `Not found` exception occurs

Comment: It doesn't look correct. As they are executed within same transaction and same session, hibernate will auto flush (not commit) anything in the session before  executing `findByMyFlag(1123)`. How `myRepo.findByMyFlag(1123)` is implemented?

Comment: just a normal `@Query(value="select * from my_table where my_flag = ?1", nativeSql=true)`

Comment: It may be that hibernate does not flush on native query. Why do you need native query query? SpringDataJPA should generate query based on your method right?`findByMyFlag` seem correct method name

Comment: ohh yes, also tried via spring-jpa, still cant access the data

Comment: Just for troubleshooting purposes, Can you add `myRepo.flush(e);` above `methodB();` and delete the `myRepo.save(e);`

Comment: tried it. the same result. currently i am looking in another perspective. database may have another data or was cleared by somebody.

Comment: It cannot be cleared as it is not committed. It looks like you created the tables manually. Your query is looking for different field than the filed that getting saved

Comment: In your comment below you note "both are on a different class methodA is in ServiceA methodB is in ServiceB –" however your question in no way reflects that.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that it uses the same session and it is part of the same transaction.  Where you're mistaken is that setting the value in the entity (without having saved yet) puts it anywhere that doing another query will find it.

In other words, the findByMyFlag in methodB is still not going to find the entity which you just modified, because the value you're searching on hasn't been saved to the database, yet.

If, on the other hand, you had searched in methodB using findByid(1), then you would have found the same entity that would have that change in it.

Answer (score 0):

In the same class, a method calls another annotated method (such as @Async, @Transational), the annotation will not take effect

Comment: both are on a different class methodA is in ServiceA methodB is in ServiceB

Comment: reason：Spring will scan the bean for @Transactional annotations when scanning the bean. If it does, Spring will dynamically generate a subclass (ie proxy class) for this bean. The proxy class inherits the original bean. At this time, when the annotated method is called, it is actually called by the proxy class,

Comment: and the proxy class will start the transaction before the call. However, if the annotated method is called by other methods in the same class, then the method call does not go through the proxy class, but directly through the original bean, so the transaction will not start, we see The phenomenon is that the @Transactional annotation is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It is only from the various comments that you have added the answer can be deduced i.e. your question itself fails to give all relevant information.

You note that you look up query is "just a normal @Query(value="select * from my_table where my_flag = ?1", nativeSql=true)".

And that is your problem: the fact you are executing a *native* sql query rather than a JPQL query.

If this was a a JPQL query then any pending changes in the same transaction would be flsuhed to the database (not committed, only flushed) in order that the query returned *accurate* results ie.e. reflected any changes pending but not yet flushed to the database.

See further here for a more detailed explanation:

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-the-auto-flush-work-in-jpa-and-hibernate/

So to fix your problem change your query to:

`@Query(value="select e from MyEntity e where e.myFlag = ?1")` i.e. a JPQL query which will trigger a flush of pending changes.

Even moving `myRepo.save(e);` above the call to methodB() will not fix it. You would need to save *and* flush for the native query to find it.

Which begs the question, why are you using a native query?